# Function which display specified element on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, this, each

I've got some problem with optimalization of my js file.

Now I've stucked at one problem: I need to use one function to hide Icon and display paragraph, one by one. I used "each" and "this", but have no idea how to display "p"only in clicked column, not in everyone

```js
function uInNumbers() {
  let itemsInColumn = $('.column i');
  let pInColumn = $('.column p');

  if (itemsInColumn.is(':visible')) {
    itemsInColumn.each(function() {
      $(this).on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggle();
        pInColumn.css({
          "display": "inline-block"
        });

      })
    });
  }
  if (pInColumn.is(":visible")) {
    pInColumn.each(function() {
      $(this).on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggle();
        itemsInColumn.css({
          "display": "inline-block"
        });
      })
    });
  }
}

uInNumbers();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

I know that pInColumns is total disaster, but have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially you can hide all the *p* elements with CSS. According to your HTML, you can simply use jQuery's [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) in the following way:

```js
$('.column i').click(function(){
  $(this).next('p').toggle();
});
```

```css
p{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">    
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>    
</div>    
<div class="column">    
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>    
</div>    
<div class="column">    
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>   
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>   
</div>   
<div class="column">   
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>   
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>   
</div>
```

***I need to use one function to hide Icon and display paragraph...***

If you really want to hide the icon then try

```
$(this).hide().next('p').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to hide all `<p>` elements then show only the one that is near to the clicked icon:

```js
$('.column .fa.fa-phone').click(function(){
  $('.column p').hide();
  $(this).closest('.column').find('p').show();
});
```

```css
.column p{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-4x"></i>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
Now I've stucked at one problem: I need to use one function to hide Icon and display paragraph, one by one. I used "each" and "this", but have no idea how to display "p"only in clicked column, not in everyone. Here is the code:
```

Comment: Thank! I've just modified your code and works perfectly :)